# SwiftUI - ForEach weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swiftui, foreach

I have a forEach loop inside a view builder function like this:

`ForEach(0..<array.count, id: \.id) { index in`

array contains a custom model, that conforms to Identifiable and has an id. Problem is when I create another foreach below this one:

`ForEach(0..<anotherArray.count, id: \.id) { index in`

now, anotherArray also has that custom model type. When running the app it will only show the first foreach, the anotherArray loop is not shown what is inside of it.

I have tried to just discard of the id: .id as this make it work as so:

`ForEach(viewModel.array.indices) { index in` and
`ForEach(viewModel.anotherArray.indices) { index in`

It works but the problem is the warning I'm getting: "Non-constant range: not an integer range"

I cannot find a clean solution for this! It's also worth mentioning that I need the loop to return me the index.

Edit: Forgot to mention this is inside a LazyVStack because I need the pinnedViews argument.

Thanks

Comment: Try Demystify SwiftUI ranges are unsafe and shouldn’t be used

Answer (score 0):

The rules are

1. `indices`, explicit integer ranges or *primitive* arrays like `[String]` or `[Int]` require `id: \.self`.
2. An object which **does not** conform to `Identifiable` but has an `id` property requires `id: \.id` (or another hashable property).
3. An object which **does** conform to `Identifiable` can omit the `id` parameter.

Comment: I understand, but it doesn't work when I have 2 Foreach of 2 different arrays with id: \.self

Comment: you can't use indices with the ForEach View because it'll crash if the array changes

Comment: @malhal You do can use `indices` because it returns always the valid indices of the current array.

Comment: only if the array doesnt change

Comment: @malhal No, always. This is (declarative) SwiftUI.

Comment: try it, delete the last item from the array

Comment: Of course I never modify an array directly in the view, I'm using a `@ObservableObject`.

Comment: Actually yes im changing one of the arrays because im using pagination and calling extra requests when needed. And I have seen the app crashing if I used index in the array inside of the ForEach, which I solved by using ``` id: \.self```, so I think @malhal is half right, it will crash if not used the id property. Problem here is it won't work if I add another forEach inside the same lazyVStack, where I need indices, and the second forEach is not shown in this case. I'm using indices to know if a cell needs to round corners on top or bottom from a list of cells.

Comment: Here is someone stuck on a crash because they used indicies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165952/swiftui-protocol-witness-for-projection-getbase-in-conformance?noredirect=1#comment130947716_74165952

Answer (score 0):

Found out that one can use `.id(UUID())` in the view inside each forEach. It will log this warning in the console:

> LazyVStackLayout: the ID 0 is used by multiple child views, this will
> give undefined results!

But this works! Although I must say I don't know if this will give any strange behaviour, for now I'm not seeing any.

EDIT: after investigating I ended up to get another solution by removing the need of index in the Foreach. Changed to:

```
ForEach(viewModel.array, id: \.id) { item in
```

In conclusion using

lazyVStack {
Foreach with index (with or without id property)
Foreach with index (with or without id property)
}

Will not work correctly. If possible avoid using index in a foreach

Comment: This is almost certainly not a good idea for most scenarios. What Demystifying SwiftUI from WWDC to see why attaching constantly-changing ids breaks the diffing system.

Comment: Incredibly inefficient, you are just redrawing everything.

Comment: I know. I'm still trying to get another solution

Answer (score 0):

The `ForEach` `View` is not a for loop.

You can't use it with array indices because it'll crash if the array changes because indices are not valid identifiers. I.e. if the item at index 1 moves to 0 it still has the index 1. If you want to use integers then it has to be a static range, e.g.

```
ForEach(0..<5) { i in

}
```

Otherwise you have to supply the ForEach with an array of structs that have an identifier, or even better implement the `Identifiable` protocol and an id property.

`id:\.self` is usually a programmer error because id is supposed to be the keypath to the unique identifier for the data not the data itself.

Comment: The model that is used inside the arrays confirm to Identifiable. Problem is using the 2 foreach with that id: \.self. It will not show the content view of the second foreach (remember this 2 foreach are inside a lazyVStack). I cannot use the id property as ```id: \.id``` of the custom model because I need the index and by using ForEach(0..<array.count, id: ```I cannot use the id property here```)  lose access to the property because its expecting an Int

Comment: *conforms to Identifiable